# Give create permission to Work Order Line Item

Tags: permission-sets, field-service-lightning, work-order

I am creating a permission set.

Need to give *Create* permission to the Work Order Line Item.

Usually, I see the below section for the object, to give Create, Read, Edit and Delete access:

[image]

But not able to see *Object Permissions* section for **Work Order Line Item**:

[image]

How to give *Create* permission to Work Order Line Item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work order and work order line item shares a master detail relationship. Work order is parent and Work order line item is child. Hence the permission will be derived through the Parent. If someone has read permission on a work order record he can also view work order line item associated with that.

So, To give create permission to a profile for Work Order Line Item, the profile must have the Create permission for Work Order.

[image]